# Convert string date time from one region to another in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, locale

I have a string date in UK format: 19 March 2014 10:17 and I want to be able to convert it to US format as a string like so: March 19, 2014, 10:17 AM, whenever the user changes region on their iPhone. This is what I have tried so far:

```
    NSString * lastResetDateTime = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LAST_STATS_REST_DATETIME]; //date I want to convert

    if(lastResetDateTime != nil){

        NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
        [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

        NSDate* lastResetDate  = [dateFormatter dateFromString:lastResetDateTime];

        self.lastResetDateTime.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:lastResetDate];
    }
```

However, lastResetDate is null, is there any other way to use the formatter for that type of date ?

Comment: Store the date internally using the appropriate data-type (i.e. `NSDate`, not `NSString`).  Following this mantra will serve you well in all aspects of your programming.

Comment: Yes, sounds like the best plan.